# Laravel - SELECT only certain columns within a `::with` controller function

Tags: select, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The following code I have is working perfectly fine, however, it returns more data than what is necessary from each table:

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $alerts = Criteria::with('bedrooms', 'properties')
        ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
        ->get();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.index', 
            array('alerts' => $alerts));
    }
```

What I'd like to do is, for example, select only the `bedroom` column out of the `bedroom` table. As it stands now, it returns all columns.

I have tried:

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $alerts = Criteria::with('bedrooms' => function($q){
            $q->select('bedroom');
        }, 'properties')
        ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
        ->get();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.index', 
            array('alerts' => $alerts));
    }
```

But I am presented with the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Any help as to how I can achieve this will be hugely appreciated.

---

**Update**

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $alerts = Criteria::with(
        ['coordinate' => function($w){
            $w->select('name', 'id');
        }],
        ['bedrooms' => function($q){
            $q->select('bedroom', 'criteria_id');
        }]
        , 'properties')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->get();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.index', 
        array('alerts' => $alerts));
}
```

The correct `select` query works for which ever is queried first. If I swap the queries around, the `bedroom` function works correctly, but the rest aren't eager loaded nor does the `select` query work.

Comment: Just a note, you might want to use `Auth::user()->id` instead of `Auth::id()` to get the current user's ID.

Comment: @msturdy, noted and changed. Many thanks.

Comment: @msturdy definitely not. If you don't have the user loaded, then it will run redundant query, while `Auth::id()` is the way to go if you need only the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an array there:

```
// note [ and ]
$alerts = Criteria::with(['bedrooms' => function($q){
        $q->select('bedroom', 'PK / FK');
    }, 'properties'])
```

Also mind that you **need to select the keys** of that relation (primary key/foreign key of the relation).

Comment: Will this work for more than one table inside the `with` function? I've added a query on to the `properties` but it still seems to be selecting all columns. Also, the eager loading of the other tables appears to have gone?

Comment: Please see the updated section @Jarek, it doesn't appear to work when I add the function to more than one table.

Comment: Yeah, the closing parenthesis was misplaced. You need to pass single array with multiple keys/closures. Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your update question is that you need to eager load other values in the same array some thing like this.

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $alerts = Criteria::with(
        ['coordinate' => function($w)
        {
            $w->select('name', 'id');
        },
        'bedrooms' => function($q)
        {
            $q->select('bedroom', 'criteria_id');
        }
        , 'properties'])
    ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->get();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.index', 
        array('alerts' => $alerts));
}
```